# Continuous-Mode Derivation of Two-Photon Interference

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, interference

I am attempting to generalize the results found for two-photon interference to systems of beam splitters.
Suppose we have a beam splitter with the following input and output relationship:

$$\hat{a_1}^\dagger(t)=\mathcal{R}\hat{a_3}^\dagger(t) + \mathcal{T}\hat{a_4}^\dagger(t)$$

$$\hat{a_2}^\dagger(t)=\mathcal{T}\hat{a_3}^\dagger(t) + \mathcal{R}\hat{a_4}^\dagger(t)$$

We can describe a state with a photon at each input arm as:

$$\left|(1_1, 1_2)_\beta\right\rangle = \int dt\int dt' \beta(t, t')\hat{a_1}^\dagger(t)\hat{a_2}^\dagger(t)\left|0\right\rangle$$

$\beta(t, t')$ is the fourier transform of the spectral amplitude for the photons.

We want to find the state of the output arms. Substituting for $\hat{a_1}^\dagger(t)$ and $\hat{a_2}^\dagger(t)$ using the first two equations defined, we can expand the previous equation to:

$$\left|(1_1, 1_2)_\beta\right\rangle = \int dt\int dt'\beta(t, t')\left[\mathcal{R}\mathcal{T}\hat{a_3}^\dagger(t)\hat{a_3}^\dagger(t')+\mathcal{R}^2\hat{a_3}^\dagger(t)\hat{a_4}^\dagger(t')+\mathcal{T}^2\hat{a_4}^\dagger(t)\hat{a_3}^\dagger(t') + \mathcal{T}\mathcal{R}\hat{a_4}^\dagger(t)\hat{a_4}^\dagger(t')\right]\left|0\right\rangle$$

Up to this point, it makes perfect sense to me. However, the next simplification, as done by Loudon in his *The Quantum Theory of Light*, 3rd edition, in Chapter 6.8 (Two-photon interference) does not make sense to me. He claims the above expression is equal to (using only "rearranging" and "suitable interchanges of the time variables") to:
$$\left|(1_1, 1_2)_\beta\right\rangle = \int dt\int dt'\left\{\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{R}\mathcal{T}\left[\beta(t, t') + \beta(t', t)\right]\left[\hat{a_3}^\dagger(t)\hat{a_3}^\dagger(t') + \hat{a_4}^\dagger(t)\hat{a_4}^\dagger(t')\right]+\left[\mathcal{R}^2\beta(t, t') + \mathcal{T}^2\beta(t', t)\right]\hat{a_3}^\dagger(t)\hat{a_4}^\dagger(t')\right\}\left|0\right\rangle$$

I don't understand how he makes this simplification. I have tried tricks with interchanging the time variables and commuters. Note that $\beta(t, t')\neq \beta(t', t)$. The only constraint on $\beta(t, t')$ is $\int dt\int dt' |\beta(t, t')|^2 = 1$.

The difference between the first and second integrand is:
$$\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{R}\mathcal{T}\left[\beta(t, t') - \beta(t', t)\right]\left[\hat{a_3}^\dagger(t)\hat{a_3}^\dagger(t') + \hat{a_4}^\dagger(t)\hat{a_4}^\dagger(t')\right] + \beta(t, t')\mathcal{T}^2\hat{a_4}^\dagger(t)\hat{a_3}^\dagger(t')-\beta(t', t)\mathcal{R}^2\hat{a_3}^\dagger(t)\hat{a_3}^\dagger(t')$$

I should suppose there is some way to prove the difference is identically zero. Is there any way to prove this? How else can one perform that final step in simplifying the integrand?

Comment: Note that you are allowed to relabel the integration variables $t\leftrightarrow t'$.